# infinite problem when do some preprocess for data set in python

Tags: python, numpy, dataset, preprocessor, infinity

how i fix this error after import bumpy, panda and matplotlib.pyplot

when i use projectDataset.csv dataset

```
dataset= pd.read_csv('projectDataset.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:,7:54].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,83].values
```

and splitting of the dataset in training dataset and test dataset

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.2, random_state = 1)
```

and Feature scaling

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
x_train = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = sc.fit_transform(x_test)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-291-3ad5b591b7f2> in <module>()
      1 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
      2 sc = StandardScaler()
----> 3 x_train = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
      4 x_test = sc.fit_transform(x_test)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
     58                     msg_err.format
     59                     (type_err,
---> 60                      msg_dtype if msg_dtype is not None else X.dtype)
     61             )
     62     # for object dtype data, we only check for NaNs (GH-13254)

ValueError: Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

this error appear to me my dataset does not have none data

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are a few `np.inf` in there. Replace them with `np.nan` would help:

```
dataset = dataset.replace([np.inf,-np.inf], np.nan)
```